# How to set Kotlin debug launch.json configurations in VS Code?

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my Kotlin Spring boot application after moving from Java to Kotlin, but the launch.json of Kotlin has different configurations than Java's, for example we're using `profiles` to switch between the environments, and when I add `"args": "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"` I'm getting `Property args is not allowed`. And in the debug console I'm getting

```
Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.42.Final:compile is not a properly formed Maven/Gradle artifact
[ERROR] java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.42.Final:compile is not a properly formed Maven/Gradle artifact
```

Here's my current Kotlin configs:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "kotlin",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Kotlin Launch",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "mainClass": "path.to.my.Application",
            "args": "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" // <--- showing error
        }
    ]
}
```

For comparison, here's my java launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}",
            "args": "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "mainClass": "path.to.my.application",
            "projectName": "spring",
            "args": "--spring.profiles.active=dev",
            "vmArgs": "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"

        }
    ]
}
```

What are the correct configs for Kotlin if I want to use `profiles` or `args`?

Comment: same question here. did you figured out how?